# Swift Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type

Tags: ios, swift

```
if let ip = indexPath {
            var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
            cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("item") as String

         }
```

error :
"Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

I'm using  xcode 6.1.1, help please.﻿

I am following this tutorial, [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ymz6i07DRM]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are saying:

```
if let ip = indexPath {
```

Swift is saying: "Just say `let ip = indexPath`, or simply use `indexPath` directly. There is no need for the `if` (or the curly braces); you don't need a condition here."

The reason is probably that at the time the tutorial you're using was designed, `indexPath` was an Optional and needed to be unwrapped. But now it is not an Optional. Apple changes the APIs from time to time.

Comment: If you don't understand what an Optional is, or why it might need to be unwrapped, see my new tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional For the "if let" way of unwrapping: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_if_construct But you don't need to know that in _this_ case, because it turns out that `indexPath` is _not_ an Optional.